# Отловить событие перед загрузкой html

Tags: javascript

Делаю 2 типа меню. Какое из них загрузится пользователю решается с помощью js относительно ширины экрана. Но проблема в том, что оно загружается после загрузки страници. Как это исправить? Как отловить событие чтоб выпрлнять js код перед загрузкой страници
И как вы в целом относитесь к такому решению? На чистом css не хочется делать
Вот сайт- glite.com.ua

Comment: Выполнять код перед загрузкой страницы? Так может вы его добавите не в конец body, а между head? Тогда он выполнится до создания структуры. И опять же, что мешает сделать прелоадер на страницу и дожидаться полной загрузки?

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем ширину экрана проверять на js. Используйте медиа-запросы css: для одних экранов одно меню показываете, другое скрываете. И наоборот.

Comment: @humster_spb Идея в том, чтоб сохранить красоту исходного кода (чисто для себя). Меню состоит из сотни строк кода, с запросами sql, скриптами и прочим. Загружать в два раза больше js - больше нагрузка на пользователя